# Reverse np.reshape for 3 dimensions in loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, reshape

I am trying to create anomalies over the time period of 2004-2009 (ClimSt-ClimEd) for a gridded data set (number of months: 192 (equal to 16 years), number of latitudes: 36, number of longitudes: 72). In order to subtract the mean from each month, relatively, I reshape TheData to (192/12, 12), 16 years per 12 months. Afterwards I need to bring the data back to their original shape (192, 36, 72).

I struggle with the 3 dim reshaping. I guess there is either something wrong in the first or the last np.reshape, not sure though.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

TheData = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(192, 36, 72))
TheMDI = -1e30
NLats = 36
NLons = 72
ClimSt = 2004
ClimEd = 2009
NewSt = 2002

print('first', TheData.shape) #prints: first (192, 36, 72)
for lt in range(NLats): # range nlats goes through 0...36
    for ln in range(NLons): # range nlons goes through 0...72
        print('second', TheData.shape) #prints: second (192, 36, 72)
        TheData = np.reshape(TheData[:,lt,ln],(len(TheData)//12,12))
        for mm in range(12):
            print('third', TheData.shape) #prints 12x: third (16, 12)
            subarr=TheData[:,mm]
            subclim=subarr[ClimSt-NewSt:(ClimEd+1)-NewSt] # creates data from 2004-2009
            climgots=np.where(subclim > TheMDI)[0] # we want to add only existing data to 2004-2009
            gots=np.where(subarr > TheMDI)[0] # we want to add only existing data to 2002-2017
            if (len(climgots) > 15):
                subarr[gots]=subarr[gots]-np.mean(subclim[climgots])
            TheData[:,mm]=subarr
        print('fourth', TheData.shape) #prints: fourth (16, 12)
        TheData[:,lt,ln] = np.reshape(TheData,np.size(TheData)) #gives: IndexError: too many indices for array
        print('fifth', TheData.shape) #should print: fifth (192, 36, 72)
```

The print output is the following:

```py
first (192, 36, 72)
second (192, 36, 72)
third (16, 12)
third (16, 12)
third (16, 12)
third (16, 12)
third (16, 12)
third (16, 12)
third (16, 12)
third (16, 12)
third (16, 12)
third (16, 12)
third (16, 12)
third (16, 12)
fourth (16, 12)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testooo.py", line 27, in <module>
    TheData[:,lt,ln] = np.reshape(TheData,np.size(TheData))
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

I am expecting an additional "fifth (192, 36, 72)".

It would be fab if you could help!

Comment: without the data or part of the data, there is no way to help

Comment: It's a netcdf file. The data is 3 dimensional: (192,36,72). Would TheData = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(192, 36, 72)) help? MDI = -1e30.

Comment: What is NewSt meant to be?

Comment: I have added now all parameters.

Comment: the current code breaks at `TheData = np.reshape(TheData[:,lt,ln],(len(TheData)//12,12))`

Comment: @makis, please try again. It should break at the very last line.

Comment: I am going to modify my answer since you posted the full code

Comment: let me know if my answer helps

Comment: Although or better as I don't really get what you are trying to do... - if you say your data is from a netcdf file: did you try or do you know about [`xarray`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/), best probably combined with [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/)? At least my feeling is that you try to do things manually on your own, which are already implemented as functions or standardized workflows in these packages... (i.e.e.g. sth like [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html) months and apply some function)

Comment: Thanks for the hint, @SpghttCd! I'll keep this in mind for next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem beyond just the error you have there, and I think I found a way to fix both issues though I'm not 100% clear on what it is you're doing with this data.

You have `TheData` for your whole data set which you're doing some work with. However when you do `TheData = np.reshape(TheData[:,lt,ln],(len(TheData)//12,12)` inside your loop, you lose all of your data not at index `lt,ln`. You need to keep your data and use some other containers for this intermediate work. See the code below, where I've made a new container for the new data and use an intermediate data variable for the work:

```
TheData = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(192, 36, 72))        

newData = np.empty((192, NLats, NLons))

for lt in range(NLats): # range nlats goes through 0...36
    for ln in range(NLons): # range nlons goes through 0...72
        intermediateData = np.reshape(TheData[:,lt,ln],(len(TheData)//12,12))
        for mm in range(12):
            subarr=intermediateData[:,mm]
            subclim=subarr[ClimSt-NewSt:(ClimEd+1)-NewSt] # creates data from 2004-2009
            climgots=np.where(subclim > TheMDI)[0] # we want to add only existing data to 2004-2009
            gots=np.where(subarr > TheMDI)[0] # we want to add only existing data to 2002-2017
            if (len(climgots) > 15):
                subarr[gots]=subarr[gots]-np.mean(subclim[climgots])
            intermediateData[:,mm]=subarr
        newData[:,lt,ln] = np.reshape(intermediateData,np.size(intermediateData))
```

I can't be certain that what is being done with the data is what you're going for, but with random data I was able to get this to run and it seems like it will at least help you get on track to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: This code breaks at `intermediateData = np.reshape(TheData[:,lt,ln],(len(TheData)//12,12))`

Comment: It doesn't break when I run it, what error are you seeing?

Comment: I added the initialization for `TheData` to the answer to ensure the right size is being used.

Comment: Fantastic! The last line adds all intermediateData for, step by step, all latitudes and longitudes to the newData which is empty in the beginning and totally full in the end of the code. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, I tested it with random values and got a full 3D array at the end. I would suggest using a small subset of data to test and verify that each step is doing what you want. For instance non of the random values were `< TheMDI` so you'll want to test that it works for that case.

Answer (score 0):

Re-writing my answer, after you have provided more information:

You have:

```
    print('fourth', TheData.shape) #prints: fourth (16, 12)
    TheData[:,lt,ln] = np.reshape(TheData,np.size(TheData)) #gives: IndexError: too many indices for array
    print('fifth', TheData.shape) #should print: fifth (192, 36, 72)
```

**The second line here i.e. `TheData[:,lt,ln]` gives the error because `TheData` is an 2D array but you try to slice it using `TheData[:,lt,ln]`**

Comment: The original TheData should be a 3D array. May I ask if it is not anymore, when within the first two loops? Does it become 1D at the point of TheData = np.reshape(TheData[:,lt,ln],(len(TheData)//12,12)) ?

Comment: Yes. See my updated answer. The code breaks in the first line actually. Are you sure that `TheData = np.reshape(TheData[:,lt,ln],(len(TheData)//12,12))` should be inside the loop and execute in each iteration? What is your goal?

Comment: It's worth noting that this will still cause all of `TheData` outside of index `[lt,ln]` to be lost, which probably isn't desired behavior.